# Is it possible to set InputScope from a webpage?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, input

If I'm creating a webpage that will be displayed in IE on Phone 7, can I specify the [InputScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521152%28VS.92%29.aspx) that text boxes in the webpage should use?

Comment: For readers coming to this question, for WP8, the following question is relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414850/can-you-declare-an-inputscope-in-a-webbrowser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. InputScope is a proprty of a `TextBox` and there is no custom attribute defined for a HTML input to use as an equivalent.

The webbrowser control will use the same SIP as the "Text" InputScope for HTML input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This what I suspect as well.  How do you know this is the case though?  All I could find was a lack of any comment on the topic.

Comment: This is based on being unable to find a way to do this and all the things that apparently different having been documented.