# Can you declare an InputScope in a WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm aware of the property InputScope in a TextBox, but is it possible to use in a WebBrowser? I actually just want to get rid of the autosuggestions, if that is possible without changing the InputScope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the input scope for each input in the HTML. This way the specific keyboard for each input type will be displayed.

See [HTML5 Input Types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp).

You can visit [this page](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/html5-input-types/) to try them.

Note that this will only work with Windows Phone 8 (IE10), because IE9, the browser in Windows Phone 7, doesn't implement it.

Answer (score 1):

InputScope is available in XAML through System.Windows.Input in System.Windows.dll, so anywhere you use it whether it web / desktop / WP7 / WP8, it is available. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscope%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Although [this tutorial for inputscope is for WP7](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/inputscope-textbox-windows), much of the theory applies to WP8

P.S. Where is your autocomplete / autosuggest code? If you post it we can possibly help you further, e.g. [see this link for how to fiddle with autosuggest on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008423/android-dont-show-autosuggest-list-when-item-is-selected)

EDIT: Ah in light of your comment; hopefully this answers your question in conjunction with the other answers supplied here [is it possible to set inputscope from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778938/is-it-possible-to-set-inputscope-from-a-webpage)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer, but you didn't quite get my question, or I didn't formulate it well enough. I'm asking for a way to set InputScope on a WebBrowser control, and the autosuggestions are coming from the system keyboard itself.